# reading a h264 RTSP stream into python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

Here is the problem

i have an IP camera that stream a h264 video using RTSP protocol, 
all i want to do is read this stream and pass it to Open CV  to decode it, 
using this function

```
cv2.imdecode()
```

how?

**Update**

i solved this problem

here is the solution : [Convert YUVj420p pixel format to RGB888 using gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574655/convert-yuvj420p-pixel-format-to-rgb888-using-gstreamer)

Comment: imdecode is for images. you need to use `cv2.VideoCapture`

Comment: i will grab frame by frame and decode it

Comment: VideoCapture does that for you. you cant do that with imdecode, which is strictly for images(jpeg,png,tiff etc). in my personal experience,videocapture also will not work in some rtsp streams, in which case you need to use extra layer to decode the frames and pass it to opencv. for instance, using vlc to do the video decoding, like `vlc.exe -I dummy --dummy-quiet rtsp://10.10.3.133/h264   :sout=#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,vb=5000,scale=1,acodec=none}:standard{access=http,mux=raw,dst=127.0.0.1:9080/frame.mjpg} vlc://quit`

Comment: well i m using now gstreamer and i have been able to read and decode the ip camera stream do u have any idea how i can pass stream to opencv

Comment: @ZawLin Thanks for the command, although I had to change `m‌​ux=raw` to `mux=ts` to make it work, `raw` doesn't seem to be a valid option there.

Comment: Solution go to 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574655/convert-yuvj420p-pixel-format-to-rgb888-using-gstreamer/24589536#24589536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
import numpy as np
import cv2

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

def YUV_stream2RGB_frame(data):

    w=640
    h=368
    size=w*h

    stream=np.fromstring(data,np.uint8) #convert data form string to numpy array

    #Y bytes  will start form 0 and end in size-1 
    y=stream[0:size].reshape(h,w) # create the y channel same size as the image

    #U bytes will start from size and end at size+size/4 as its size = framesize/4 
    u=stream[size:(size+(size/4))].reshape((h/2),(w/2))# create the u channel  itssize=framesize/4

    #up-sample the u channel to be the same size as the y channel and frame using pyrUp func in opencv2
    u_upsize=cv2.pyrUp(u)

    #do the same for v channel 
    v=stream[(size+(size/4)):].reshape((h/2),(w/2))
    v_upsize=cv2.pyrUp(v)

    #create the 3-channel frame using cv2.merge func watch for the order
    yuv=cv2.merge((y,u_upsize,v_upsize))

    #Convert TO RGB format
    rgb=cv2.cvtColor(yuv,cv2.cv.CV_YCrCb2RGB)

    #show frame
    cv2.imshow("show",rgb)
    cv2.waitKey(5)

def on_new_buffer(appsink):

   sample = appsink.emit('pull-sample')
   #get the buffer
   buf=sample.get_buffer()
   #extract data stream as string
   data=buf.extract_dup(0,buf.get_size())
   YUV_stream2RGB_frame(data)
   return False

def Init():

   CLI="rtspsrc name=src location=rtsp://192.168.1.20:554/live/ch01_0 latency=10   !decodebin ! appsink name=sink"

   #simplest way to create a pipline
   pipline=Gst.parse_launch(CLI)

   #getting the sink by its name set in CLI
   appsink=pipline.get_by_name("sink")

   #setting some important properties of appsnik
   appsink.set_property("max-buffers",20) # prevent the app to consume huge part of memory
   appsink.set_property('emit-signals',True) #tell sink to emit signals
   appsink.set_property('sync',False) #no sync to make decoding as fast as possible

   appsink.connect('new-sample', on_new_buffer) #connect signal to callable func

def run():
    pipline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    GObject.MainLoop.run()


Init()
run()
```